# stat() returns error

Tags: c, stat, strftime, localtime

I have to know the modification date of some files in a folder. It works, but not with all types of files.
For example it works with .c, .txt, but it doesn't work with other types such .mp4, .jpg and .mp3 (the application I'm creating have to work with multimedia files in general). It prints "Cannot display the time.", so I suppose the problem is on stat(). Thanks.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char parola[12]="", hash[32]="", esadecimale[1000]="", system3[100]="./md5 ";
int i, len, len2;
int bytes;
char cwd[1024];

int main(void)
{
char t[100] = "";
struct stat b;
DIR *dp;
char destinationFolder[100] = "/Users/mattiazeni/Desktop/Prova/"; //Me la passa da sopra
struct dirent *dir_p;
dp = opendir(destinationFolder);
if ( dp == NULL ) exit(1);

len = strlen(destinationFolder);

for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
    system3[i+6]=destinationFolder[i];
}

while( ( dir_p = readdir(dp) ) != NULL ) {
    if (dir_p -> d_name[0] != '.') {
        //printf("%s\n", dir_p -> d_name);
        len2 = strlen(dir_p -> d_name);
        for (i=0;i<len2;i++) {
            if (dir_p -> d_name[i] == ' '){ //Mi serve per correggere i nomi dei file con spazi
                system3[i+len+6]='\\';   
            }
            else system3[i+len+6]=dir_p -> d_name[i];
        }
        system(system3); //Passa il valore a md5 che calcola l'hash e lo stampa nel file che ci serve insieme al persorso/nome del file

        FILE *fp;
        if((fp=fopen("userDatabase.txt", "ab"))==NULL) {
            printf("Error while opening the file..\n");
            fclose (fp);
        }
        else {
            if (!stat(dir_p -> d_name, &b)) {
            strftime(t, 100, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime( &b.st_mtime));         //C'è ancora qualche errore!!
            fprintf(fp, "%s", t);           
            }
            else {
                perror(0);
                fprintf(fp, "error");
            }
            fprintf(fp, " initialized");
            fprintf(fp, "\n");
        }
        fclose (fp);
        for (i=len+6;i<len+6+len2;i++) {
            system3[i]=' ';
        }
    }
}   
closedir(dp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `perror` instead of the "cannot display time" printf to know what error you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

Use `perror()`. Also shouldn't you use `st_mtime`?

```
stat:
       On success, zero is returned. 
       On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
```

99% sure it is because `dir_p -> d_name` does not exist, which in turn probably is because of a localization issue.

You could do something like:

```
fprintf(stderr, 
        "Unable to stat %s\n",
        dir_p->d_name); 
perror(0);
```

Also; shouldn't it be `->f_name` and not `->d_name` if you are checking file status? - (*Unless you use d_name for file name off course.*)

And your `fclose(fp)` is outside your `fp == NULL` check. As you do not return or otherwise abort the flow you risk an SIGSEGV if the `fopen` fail.

---

Edit: What do you get with something like this?

```
#include <unistd.h>

char cwd[1024];

...  


} else {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "Unable to stat '%s'\n",
            dir_p->d_name);
    perror(0);

    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL) {
        perror("getcwd() error");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "in directory  '%s'\n",
                cwd);
    }
}
```

---

Edit2:

First; I said `getcwd() != NULL` should be `==`. Se change. (Bad by me.)

The problem in your code. (There is a few more) but regarding stat - you use d_name from `readdir`. This is *only* filename; not dir+filename. Thus; you get i.e.:

```
stat(dir_p->d_name, ...)
```

Which becomes i.e.:

```
stat("file.mp4", ...)
```

Easiest quick-fix (tho dirty) would be:

```
/* you need to terminate the system string after your for loop */
system3[i + len + 6] = '\0';

system(system3);

if (!stat(system3 + 6, &b)) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I use dir_p -> d_name because I scan the directory in order to know which files are in it, and then for each file I want to know the modification date.

With perror I get "No such file or directory". But I don't understand why, the files are there.. Also because on those files I calculate the md5 hash, and it worls fine, the problem is only for the date.

Comment: @phcaze: What does `dir_p->d_name` print as? Also; you could check current working directory if you do some changes to that. Use something like the new code above. What does it print?

Comment: dir_p->d_name prints the path with the filename, /Users/user/Desktop/file.mp4.

With your code it prints on the screen "/Users/user/Desktop/file.mp4 getcwd() error: Undefined error: 0".

Comment: @phcaze Updated the sample code. On another note; you say you stat the directory, but `/Users/user/Desktop/file.mp4` looks like a file. Do you have a more complete sample to post? Which can be compiled to reproduce what you experience?

Comment: @phcaze: also note that your escape sequence fail (you pad with \\ but do not add the space). You have some bound issues on lengths of arrays. I.e. if len or len2 > 93. Even worse where you "blank out" by setting to ' ' after use. If you have a big enough array simply add a '\0' where you want it to end - old data beyond this is not read when array is interpreted as C-string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the complete pathname for stat(). Stat does not know which directory you are interested in.

```
... 
char  bigbuff[PATH_MAX];

sprintf( bigbuff, "%s/%s", destinationFolder, dir_p->d_name);

rc = stat (bigbuff, &b);
...
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem! :) Thanks. But why it gives me error only with some files?

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working code in order to scan a directory for files, and print them on a txt output file with the modification date:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char system3[6]="./md5 ";

int main(void)
{
char t[100] = "";
char bigbuff[200];
struct stat b;
char destinationFolder[100] = "/Users/mattiazeni/Desktop/Prova"; //Me la passa da sopra
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dir_p;
dp = opendir(destinationFolder);
if ( dp == NULL ) exit(1);
while( ( dir_p = readdir(dp) ) != NULL ) {
    if (dir_p -> d_name[0] != '.') {
        sprintf( bigbuff, "%s%s/%s",system3, destinationFolder, dir_p->d_name);
        system(bigbuff); 

        FILE *fp;
        if((fp=fopen("userDatabase.txt", "ab"))==NULL) {
            printf("Error while opening the file..\n");
            fclose (fp);
        }
        else {
            sprintf( bigbuff, "%s/%s", destinationFolder, dir_p->d_name);
            if (!stat(bigbuff, &b)) {
            strftime(t, 100, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime( &b.st_mtime));         //C'è ancora qualche errore!!
            fprintf(fp, "%s", t);           
            }
            else {
                perror(0);
                fprintf(fp, "error");
            }
            fprintf(fp, "\n");
        }
        fclose (fp);
    }
}   
closedir(dp);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks all for the help!