# C get owner and group of file/directory

Tags: c, linux, owner

I getting the error segmentation fault when I run my C program. This is my code sample to get the owner and the group of the `file/directory`:

```
    struct stat sb;
    char outstr[200];

    stat(file_or_dir_name, &sb);
            
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(sb.st_uid);
    struct group  *gr = getgrgid(sb.st_gid);

    printf("%s %s\n", pw->pw_name, gr->gr_name);
```

The code run through the directory multiple times, but then at one file I get an error at `pw->pw_name`. Is it possible that some `files/directories` have no owner or why could I get the `"Segmentation fault"`?

UPDATE:
After error checking I got the following results (like -ls in find):

> 119    0 ---xrwxr--  91 - daemon  9007206 Apr 29 00:03 ./Test/test.txt
>
> 119    0 ---xrwxr--  91 - daemon  9007206 Apr 29 00:03 ./Test/Test2
>
> 119    0 ---xrwxr--  91 - daemon  9007206 Apr 29 00:03 ./Test/Test2/test2.txt

Whats wrong with this files/directories?

Comment: Does the output shown match the code shown? I doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the return values for getpwuid and getgrgid.  You are not doing basic error checking on the stat function either.  Error check as much as you can.  Assume nothing works.

Comment: could you please provide me a samples as error checking? should I check against NULL? and does it mean that a file could have no owner?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269132/stat-returns-error

Answer (score 2):

From your `ls` output, notice that you have `daemon 9007206` for owner/group.

This means that the `uid` was found [by `getpwuid`] in `/etc/passwd` [or equiv].

But the group was *not* found [by `getgrgid`--which would return `NULL`] in `/etc/group` [or equiv].

`ls` handled this and printed the numeric value for `gid`.

*Side note:* `9007206` seems a little screwy to me.